# Submitting multipart form leads to internal server error on Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multipart, server-error

When submitting a simple multipart form, the server crashes and displays "Internal server error".
I have scaled down the form to the minimal:

```
<%= form_for @media_object, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :media_object_image %>
    <%= f.submit "Create!" %>
<% end %>
```

The log trace:

```
ERROR ArgumentError: unexpected prefix: {"RackMultipart"=>nil, ""=>nil}
    /Users/christer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:111:in `make_tmpname'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:129:in `create'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tempfile.rb:132:in `initialize'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:22:in `new'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:22:in `block in create'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:135:in `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:59:in `block in parse'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:56:in `loop'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:56:in `parse'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `parse_multipart'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:375:in `parse_multipart'
    /Users/christer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@teamhubs4/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:207:in `POST'
```

Googling around turns up multipart submission problems with Rails 4.2 due to maximum number of open multipart files, but this is definitely different.

I'm running Rails 4.2.6 with Ruby 2.3.

Comment: Your error message and stack trace are quite similar to the one posted on imgur [issue #4](https://github.com/dncrht/imgur/issues/4). You might like to try removing imgur from your Gemfile if it is referenced there.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not using the imgur gem, Phil Ross put me on the right track. I do indeed extend the Array class with a to_hash method. Removing this extensions, and voila!, things work as they should.

Answer (score 0):

`imgur` is not alone. [`dropbox` gem](https://github.com/RISCfuture/dropbox) is also [known](https://github.com/RISCfuture/dropbox/issues/52) to cause this. Check your Gemfile.